# Drop a key-value pair from document when it isn't exist and update when it is exist

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Insert this

```
db.test.insertMany([{"_id":"T1","us":"a11","jp":"b21"},{"_id":"T2","us":"a12","jp":"b22"},{"_id":"T3","us":"a13","jp":"b23"},{"_id":"T4","us":"a14","jp":"b24"}])
```

My data looks like

```
{ "_id" : "T1",  "us": "a11",  "jp": "b21" }
{ "_id" : "T2",  "us": "a12",  "jp": "b22" }
{ "_id" : "T3",  "us": "a13",  "jp": "b23" }
{ "_id" : "T4",  "us": "a14",  "jp": "b24" }
```

I have a key list, and a key-value list

```
pks=['T1', 'T2']
kvs=[{"us": "a88"}, {"us": "a99"}]
```

If there are another key in my documents, ex: 'cn', 'uk', kvs will change to

```
kvs=[{"jp": "b55"}, {"jp": "b99"}]
```

The key in the kvs list will be the same. But may be change another time.

Use kvs to update if _id in pks then change the value of `us`, 
or else delete `us` from all documents that its _id not in pks

That will result

```
{ "_id" : "T1",  "us": "a88",  "jp": "b21" }
{ "_id" : "T2",  "us": "a99",  "jp": "b22" }
{ "_id" : "T3",             ,  "jp": "b23" }
{ "_id" : "T4",             ,  "jp": "b24" }
```

Is there an API I can use?

How to do?

Or if it is to hard to solve the problem, change `kvs` or `pks` is ok.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't care about performance
here is my answer(pymongo)

```
pks=['T1', 'T2']
kvs=[{"us": "a88"}, {"us": "a99"}]
for i in range(len(pks)):
    db.test.update_many( {'$or': [{'_id': pks[i]}, {'cn': pks[i]} ]}, 
                   { '$set': { list(kvs[i].keys())[0]: list(kvs[i].values())[0] } })
    db.test.update_many({'$and': [{'_id': {'$nin': pks}}, {'cn': {'$nin': pks}}]}, 
                     {'$unset': { list(kvs[i].keys())[0] : 1 } })
```